# Shell script to check server state

Tags: shell-script, awk, quoting

I am writing a script that would ssh into the VMWare server and check if the VMs are up or not. There's some error in the `server=awk "/$i/{print $2}" /home/dharmit/scripts/vmids` line. I am getting following error

```
./server_notify.sh: line 38: /688/{print }: No such file or directory
```

I know that I have made some error in quoting. But I can't find what the error is.

```
for i in {144,528,544,576,592,624,640,688}
do
        ssh root@some.ip vim-cmd vmsvc/power.getstate $i | grep off > /dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
                server=awk "/$i/{print $2}" /home/dharmit/scripts/vmids
                echo "$server is Down"
        fi
done
```

Contents of /home/dharmit/scripts/vmids

```
144 Web Server
528 N-Zimbra Mail Server
544 Zenoss
576 OTRS Supporting Tool
592 Proconsol
624 SVN
640 SFTP
688 FTP
```

Can someone please point me where I am making a mistake and what the solution is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing backquotes around the awk command and the double quotes are allowing $2 to be interpolated by the shell instead of awk.  The server= line should read:

```
server=`awk "/$i/"' {print $2}' /home/dharmit/scripts/vmids`
```

The double quotes allow $i to be interpolated by the shell, which is what you apparently want.  The single quotes prevent shell interpolation of $2.  The backquotes cause the awk command to be run and its result turned into a string that becomes the value of the `server` variable.